# Generate add() and remove() methods automatically for an @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-roo

I have an entity containing an `@ElementCollection` of `String`s:

```
@RooJavaBean
public class Foo {

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> names;

}
```

Roo generates `getNames()` and `setNames(Set<String>)`. Is there any way to also generate `addName(String)` and `removeName(String)` methods? Or, besides Roo, are there any best practices for how to implement those methods? Writing the same code for every class that holds an `@ElementCollection` just feels not right.

Comment: It will just provide you the setter and getter of your properties not more than that which is standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add/remove but just doing obj.getNames().add() or obj.getNames().remove(name).  I don't see a benefit of having a method specifically for adding when you can chain it together.  The only time I can see needing a specific add/remove/replace method on a Collection in an entity is if you need to do specific logic around the add/remove/replace, in which case Roo would be useless anyway.

Comment: It works (just have to add a constructor for the Set). Before, I always did `myList = getNames()` ... `myList.add("bla")` ... `setNames(myList)`. #-)